# convert RFC3999 date to R DateTime format

Tags: r, datetime

What am I doing wrong here?

RFC3999 to R DateTime:

```
as.Date("2014-06-18T15:00:00.000000Z",format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S") 
#expected: 2014-06-18 15:00:00
```

DateTime to RFC3999:

```
as.Date("2013-07-16",format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S") 
#expected: 2013-07-16T00:00:00.000000Z
```

Comment: `Date` is a date format, not a datetime format. Use `as.POSIXct` or `strptime`. For the second, don't give formatting arguments for parts that aren't there, or it will give you `NA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`as.Date` coerces to the `Date` class, which is *only* a date class, not a datetime one. Base R has two datetime classes, POSIXct and POSIXlt, the prime difference being in how they internally store data—as a single number of seconds from an origin for POSIXct, and as a list for POSIXlt. For most uses they're both fine, though it is worth noting that Hadley Wickham is firmly in the POSIXct camp, and thus the `tbl` structures of his packages play nicer with it.

To actually use this information, the first simply becomes

```
# for POSIXct
as.POSIXct("2014-06-18T15:00:00.000000Z", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S") 
# [1] "2014-06-18 15:00:00 EDT"

# for POSIXlt
strptime("2014-06-18T15:00:00.000000Z", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S") 
# [1] "2014-06-18 15:00:00 EDT"
```

For the second, you can't pass more parsing tokens than you have parts to parse, or you'll get `NA`.

```
# if you want a Date
as.Date("2013-07-16",format="%Y-%m-%d") 
# [1] "2013-07-16"

# if you want POSIXct (note default printing is simplified, but HMS are stored as zeros)
as.POSIXct("2013-07-16",format="%Y-%m-%d") 
# [1] "2013-07-16 EDT"

# if you want POSIXlt (same printing behavior)
strptime("2013-07-16",format="%Y-%m-%d")
# [1] "2013-07-16 EDT"
```